# How can we feed bytearray of an image in input of ffmpeg for doing direct operation for live streaming to RTMP server

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg

What I am doing now is:

I have a stream from a source, that give me *byte array* for each frame. I have to save that *byte array* to *JPEG* file. Each of the frames are being saved in memory. Then I'am streaming those *JPEG* to server using the *FFMPEG* command.

What I want to do is:

I want to skip the step of storing each frame as *JPEG*. I want to directly stream the *byte array* to *RTMP* server.

The *FFMPEG* command I am using is :-

```
ffmpeg -framerate 10 -i c:\Stream\img%03d.jpg -f flv rtmp://192.168.243.195/live/ac71e
```