# Stream image from Android with FFMPEG

Tags: python, java, android, ffmpeg, stdin

I'm currently receiving images from an external source as byte array and I would like to send it as raw video format via ffmpeg to a stream URL, where I have a RTSP server that receives RTSP streams ([a similar unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41956604/how-can-we-feed-bytearray-of-an-image-in-input-of-ffmpeg-for-doing-direct-operat)). However, I haven't worked with FFMPEG in Java, so i can't find an example on how to do it. I have a callback that copies the image bytes to a byte array as follows:

```
        public class MainActivity extends Activity {
            final String rtmp_url = "rtmp://192.168.0.12:1935/live/test";
            private int PREVIEW_WIDTH = 384;
            private int PREVIEW_HEIGHT = 292;
            private String TAG = "MainActivity";
            String ffmpeg = Loader.load(org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.ffmpeg.class);
            final String command[] = {ffmpeg,
                            "-y",  //Add "-re" for simulated readtime streaming.
                            "-f", "rawvideo",
                            "-vcodec", "rawvideo",
                            "-pix_fmt", "bgr24",
                            "-s", (Integer.toString(PREVIEW_WIDTH) + "x" + Integer.toString(PREVIEW_HEIGHT)),
                            "-r", "10",
                            "-i", "pipe:",
                            "-c:v", "libx264",
                            "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p",
                            "-preset", "ultrafast",
                            "-f", "flv",
                            rtmp_url};
            
      private UVCCamera mUVCCamera;

public void handleStartPreview(Object surface) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    Log.e(TAG, "handleStartPreview:mUVCCamera" + mUVCCamera + " mIsPreviewing:");
    if ((mUVCCamera == null)) return;
    Log.e(TAG, "handleStartPreview2 ");
    try {
        mUVCCamera.setPreviewSize(mWidth, mHeight, 1, 26, 0, UVCCamera.DEFAULT_BANDWIDTH, 0);
        Log.e(TAG, "handleStartPreview3 mWidth: " + mWidth + "mHeight:" + mHeight);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        try {
            // fallback to YUV mode
            mUVCCamera.setPreviewSize(mWidth, mHeight, 1, 26, UVCCamera.DEFAULT_PREVIEW_MODE, UVCCamera.DEFAULT_BANDWIDTH, 0);
            Log.e(TAG, "handleStartPreview4");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
            callOnError(e1);
            return;
        }
    }
    Log.e(TAG, "handleStartPreview: startPreview1");
    int result = mUVCCamera.startPreview();
    mUVCCamera.setFrameCallback(mIFrameCallback, UVCCamera.PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBX);
    mUVCCamera.startCapture();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Camera Started",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process process = pb.start();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    OutputStream writer = process.getOutputStream();
    byte img[] = new byte[192*108*3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 108; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 192; x++)
            {
                byte r = (byte)((x * y + i) % 255);
                byte g = (byte)((x * y + i*10) % 255);
                byte b = (byte)((x * y + i*20) % 255);
                img[(y*192 + x)*3] = b;
                img[(y*192 + x)*3+1] = g;
                img[(y*192 + x)*3+2] = r;
            }
        }

        writer.write(img);
    }

    writer.close();
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    process.waitFor();
}
public static void buildRawFrame(Mat img, int i)
{
    int p = img.cols() / 60;
    img.setTo(new Scalar(60, 60, 60));
    String text = Integer.toString(i+1);
    int font = Imgproc.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX;
    Point pos = new Point(img.cols()/2-p*10*(text.length()), img.rows()/2+p*10);
    Imgproc.putText(img, text, pos, font, p, new Scalar(255, 30, 30), p*2);  //Blue number
}
```

Additionally: [Android Camera Capture using FFmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280722/android-camera-capture-using-ffmpeg)

uses ffmpeg to capture frame by frame from native android camera and instead of pushing it via RTMP, they used to generate a video file as output. Although how the image was passed via ffmpeg was not informed.

frameData is my byte array and I'd like to know how can I write the necessary ffmpeg commands using ProcessBuilder to send an image via RTSP using ffmpeg for a given URL.

An example of what I am trying to do, In Python 3 I could easily do it by doing:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import socket
import sys
import pickle
import struct
import subprocess

fps = 25
width = 224
height = 224
rtmp_url = 'rtmp://192.168.0.13:1935/live/test'
    
    
    
    command = ['ffmpeg',
               '-y',
               '-f', 'rawvideo',
               '-vcodec', 'rawvideo',
               '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',
               '-s', "{}x{}".format(width, height),
               '-r', str(fps),
               '-i', '-',
               '-c:v', 'libx264',
               '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
               '-preset', 'ultrafast',
               '-f', 'flv',
               rtmp_url]
    
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    
    while(True):
        frame = np.random.randint([255], size=(224, 224, 3))
        frame = frame.astype(np.uint8)
        p.stdin.write(frame.tobytes())
```

I would like to do the same thing in Android

Update: I can reproduce @Rotem 's answer on Netbeans although, in Android I am getting NullPointer exception error when trying to execute pb.start().

```
    Process: com.infiRay.XthermMini, PID: 32089
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1012)
        at com.infiRay.XthermMini.MainActivity.handleStartPreview(MainActivity.java:512)
        at com.infiRay.XthermMini.MainActivity.startPreview(MainActivity.java:563)
        at com.infiRay.XthermMini.MainActivity.access$1000(MainActivity.java:49)
        at com.infiRay.XthermMini.MainActivity$3.onConnect(MainActivity.java:316)
        at com.serenegiant.usb.USBMonitor$3.run(USBMonitor.java:620)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
2022-06-02 11:47:20.300 32089-1049/com.infiRay.XthermMini E/libUVCCamera: [1049*UVCPreviewIR.cpp:505:uvc_preview_frame_callback]:receive err data
2022-06-02 11:47:20.304 32089-1049/com.infiRay.XthermMini E/libUVCCamera: [1049*UVCPreviewIR.cpp:505:uvc_preview_frame_callback]:receive err data
2022-06-02 11:47:20.304 32089-1049/com.infiRay.XthermMini E/libUVCCamera: [1049*UVCPreviewIR.cpp:505:uvc_preview_frame_callback]:receive err data
2022-06-02 11:47:20.308 32089-1049/com.infiRay.XthermMini E/libUVCCamera: [1049*UVCPreviewIR.cpp:505:uvc_preview_frame_callback]:receive err data
2022-06-02 11:47:20.312 32089-32089/com.infiRay.XthermMini E/MainActivity: onPause:
2022-06-02 11:47:20.314 32089-32581/com.infiRay.XthermMini I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 32089 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Do you mean writing to stdin pipe of FFmpeg sub-process in JAVA?

Comment: I am not sure if in Java we can do that, from what I was looking It could be done ProcessBuilder, although if Java has stdin pipe, that would be great.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to create a video from an array of images in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40456156/295004) and [how to make RTSP server at android phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40863153/295004)

Comment: I don't know enough JAVA, and don't know the limitation on Android. Is it possible to create a sub-process like this: `p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)`? (when `cmd = "ffmpeg"...` with arguments list), Then use `p_stdin = DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream())`, and write data to stdin: `p_stdin.write(arr)`?

Comment: It's possible on Android as well, as long as your application uses Android API below 29, or you'll get "Permission denied", see https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/issues/1127#issuecomment-643700534

Comment: Although, I am getting "W/System.err: Warning: Version of org.bytedeco:ffmpeg could not be found."

Comment: That warning is normal on Android because the build system strips away the properties where the version information is stored.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a JAVA implementation that resembles the Python code:

The example writes raw video frames (byte arrays) to stdin pipe of FFmpeg sub-process:

```
 _____________             ___________                  ________ 
| JAVA byte   |           |           |                |        |
| Array       |   stdin   | FFmpeg    |                | Output |
| BGR (format)| --------> | process   | -------------> | stream |
|_____________| raw frame |___________| encoded video  |________|
```

Main stages:

- Initialize FFmpeg command arguments:

  ```
   final String command[] = {"ffmpeg", "-f", "rawvideo", ...}
  ```
- Create `ProcessBuilder` that executes FFmpeg as a sub-process:

  ```
   ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
  ```
- Redirect stderr (required for reading FFmpeg messages), without it, the sub-process halts:

  ```
   pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
  ```
- Start FFmpeg sub-process, and create `BufferedReader`:

  ```
   Process process = pb.start();
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
  ```
- Create `OutputStream` for writing to stdin pipe of FFmpeg sub-process:

  ```
   OutputStream writer = process.getOutputStream();
  ```
- Write raw video frames to stdin pipe of FFmpeg sub-process in a loop:

  ```
   byte img[] = new byte[width*height*3];

   for (int i = 0; i < n_frmaes; i++)
   {
       //Fill img with pixel data
       ...
       writer.write(img);
   }
  ```
- Close stdin, read and print stderr content, and wait for sub-process to finish:

  ```
   writer.close();

   String line;
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
   {
       System.out.println(line);
   }        

   process.waitFor();
  ```

---

Code sample:
The following code sample writes 10 raw video frames with size 192x108 to FFmpeg.
Instead of streaming to RTMP, we are writing the result to `test.flv` file (for testing).
The example uses hard coded strings and numbers (for simplicity).

Note:
The code sample assume FFmpeg executable is in the execution path.

```
package myproject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class FfmpegVideoWriter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        final String rtmp_url = "test.flv"; //Set output file (instead of output URL) for testing.
        
        final String command[] = {"ffmpeg",
                                  "-y",  //Add "-re" for simulated readtime streaming.
                                  "-f", "rawvideo",
                                  "-vcodec", "rawvideo",
                                  "-pix_fmt", "bgr24",
                                  "-s", "192x108",
                                  "-r", "10",
                                  "-i", "pipe:",
                                  "-c:v", "libx264",
                                  "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p",
                                  "-preset", "ultrafast",
                                  "-f", "flv",
                                  rtmp_url};
        
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483830/process-waitfor-never-returns
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);    //Create ProcessBuilder
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true); //Redirect stderr
        Process process = pb.start();               
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        
        //Create OutputStream for writing to stdin pipe of FFmpeg sub-process.
        OutputStream writer = process.getOutputStream();
        
        byte img[] = new byte[192*108*3];   //Dummy image 
        
        //Write 10 video frames to stdin pipe of FFmpeg sub-process
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            //Fill image with some arbitrary pixel values
            for (int y = 0; y < 108; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < 192; x++)
                {
                    //Arbitrary RGB values:
                    byte r = (byte)((x * y + i) % 255); //Red component
                    byte g = (byte)((x * y + i*10) % 255); //Green component
                    byte b = (byte)((x * y + i*20) % 255); //Blue component
                    img[(y*192 + x)*3] = b; 
                    img[(y*192 + x)*3+1] = g;
                    img[(y*192 + x)*3+2] = r;
                }
            }
            
            writer.write(img);  //Write img to FFmpeg
        }
        
        writer.close();  //Close stdin pipe.

        //Read and print stderr content
        //Note: there may be cases when FFmpeg keeps printing messages, so it may not be the best solution to empty the buffer only at the end.
        //We may consider adding an argument `-loglevel error` for reducing verbosity.
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }        
       
        process.waitFor();
    }
}
```

---

The code was tested in my PC (with Windows 10), and I am not sure it's going to work  with Android...

The above sample is simplistic and generic, in your case you may use `rgba` pixel format and write `FrameData` inside `onFrame` method.

Sample video frame ("arbitrary pixel values"):
[image]

---

### Update:

The following code sample uses JavaCV - writes Mat data to FFmpeg:

```
package myproject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

public class FfmpegVideoWriter {
    static { System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); }
    
    //Build synthetic "raw BGR" image for testing
    public static void buildRawFrame(Mat img, int i)
    {
        int p = img.cols() / 60;    //Used as font size factor.
        img.setTo(new Scalar(60, 60, 60));  //Fill image with dark gray color
        String text = Integer.toString(i+1);
        int font = Imgproc.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX;
        Point pos = new Point(img.cols()/2-p*10*(text.length()), img.rows()/2+p*10);
        Imgproc.putText(img, text, pos, font, p, new Scalar(255, 30, 30), p*2);  //Blue number
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        final int cols = 192;
        final int rows = 108;
        
        final String rtmp_url = "test.flv"; //Set output file (instead of output URL) for testing.
        
        final String command[] = {"ffmpeg",
                                  "-y",  //Add "-re" for simulated readtime streaming.
                                  "-f", "rawvideo",
                                  "-vcodec", "rawvideo",
                                  "-pix_fmt", "bgr24",
                                  "-s", (Integer.toString(cols) + "x" + Integer.toString(rows)),
                                  "-r", "10",
                                  "-i", "pipe:",
                                  "-c:v", "libx264",
                                  "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p",
                                  "-preset", "ultrafast",
                                  "-f", "flv",
                                  rtmp_url};
        
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483830/process-waitfor-never-returns
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);    //Create ProcessBuilder
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true); //Redirect stderr
        Process process = pb.start();               
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        
        //Create OutputStream for writing to stdin pipe of FFmpeg sub-process.
        OutputStream writer = process.getOutputStream();
        
        //Dummy image (BGR pixel format).
        Mat img = new Mat(rows, cols, CvType.CV_8UC3, Scalar.all(0));
        
        byte buffer[] = new byte[cols*rows*3]; //Byte array for storing img data    
        
        //Write 10 video frames to stdin pipe of FFmpeg sub-process
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            buildRawFrame(img, i); //Build image with blue frame counter.
                       
            img.get(0, 0, buffer); //Copy img data to buffer (not sure if this is the best solution).  
            
            writer.write(buffer); //Write buffer (raw video frame as byte array) to FFmpeg
        }
        
        writer.close(); //Close stdin pipe.

        //Read and print stderr content
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }        
       
        process.waitFor();
    }
}
```

---

Sample output frame:
[image]

Comment: I was able to replicate on netbeans using rtsp, now I am trying to use JavaCV for the ffmpeg, but there are currently some errors in it, so I am trying to fix it, I will upate the comment if I manage to get it right

Comment: I updated my answer with code sample that uses JavaCV. I don't know if that is what you are looking for, but it is more interesting than writing arbitrary values...

Comment: for some reason it deadlocks on android

Comment: Is there a deadlock with the simple example ("arbitrary pixel values") in a short loop? Try adding `"-re"` argument (it may free some CPU utilization).

Comment: This approach works on android version 9 below. Apparently, android 10 or above you can no longer call executables during code execution, so it won't load javacv's ffmpeg.

Comment: We have been warned (by Samuel Audet comment): **It's possible on Android as well, as long as your application uses Android API below 29, or you'll get "Permission denied"**. I guess the post may still be helpful for other platforms. It is likely that there are other approaches that works with Android 10, but I have zero experience with Android development.

Answer (score 0):

I found using [ffmpeg-kit](https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit) for Android slightly more convenient than invoking the ffmpeg binary using ProcessBuilder.

The simplest way to pass arbitrary data (ie. images as bytes[]) to ffmpeg is to make use of [named pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe).

The pipe is created in `{app_data}/cache/pipes/fk_pipe_1` and can be accessed like any Unix file with a FileOutputStream.

Note that the ffmpeg command is only executed once data can be read from the pipe. More info can be found in the [ffmpeg-kit wiki](https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit/wiki/Pipe-Support).

In some cases it may be easier to access the camera directly, this is [supported](https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit/wiki/Camera-Support) for API level 24 and higher.

```
String rtmp_url = "rtp://127.0.0.1:9000";

String pipe1 = FFmpegKitConfig.registerNewFFmpegPipe(context);

FFmpegKit.executeAsync("-re -f rawvideo -pixel_format bgr24 -video_size 640x480 -i " + pipe1 + " -f rtp_mpegts" + " " + rtmp_url, new FFmpegSessionCompleteCallback() {

    @Override
    public void apply(FFmpegSession session) {
        SessionState state = session.getState();
        ReturnCode returnCode = session.getReturnCode();
        // CALLED WHEN SESSION IS EXECUTED
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("FFmpeg process exited with state %s and rc %s.%s", state, returnCode, session.getFailStackTrace()));
    }
}, new LogCallback() {

    @Override
    public void apply(com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.Log log) {
        // CALLED WHEN SESSION PRINTS LOGS
    }
}, new StatisticsCallback() {

    @Override
    public void apply(Statistics statistics) {
        // CALLED WHEN SESSION GENERATES STATISTICS
    }
});

byte img[] = new byte[640*480*3];   // dummy image
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pipe1);
try {
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) { // write 100 empty frames
        out.write(img);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    out.close();
```